# Operations on pandas dataframe between values of specific columns / rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to pandas, I'm trying to manage some dataframe operations with pandas where I have 4 columns on a multi-index dataframe and where I need an extra column where the value in that column would be equal to the value in one row divided by a specific row.

In my example below, I would like for each entry, to have the new column "Agg" be the result of the column "Values" for each Type (1, 2, 3) divided by the "Values" for Calc.

```
        Date        Values  Agg
2016-01-01  Type 1    17     1.7
            Type 2    23     2.3
            Type 3    11     1.1
            Calc      10     1.0
2016-01-02  Type 1    25     0.25
            Type 2    39     0.39
            Type 3    34     0.34
            Calc      100    1.00
2016-01-03  Type 1    20     1.00
            Type 2    9      0.45
            Type 2    12     0.60
            Calc      20     1.00
```

In my actual code I have a groupby "Date" and other indexes: these changes depending on the results from a query to the db.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry are you after `df['Agg'] = df['Values'].div(df['Values'].iloc[-1])`?

Comment: Hello Ed, thanks for your reply. In my code I have multiple dates and a "Calc" row value for each. I need to find a way to mention that I want that specific value for the division for a given date in index.

Comment: Can you flesh out your question to explain better

Comment: I edited the code in the initial post. The dataframe is massive with a lot of dates; what I want to achieve is to be able to, no matter the size of the dataframe, always calculate "Type n" / "Calc" for the value field and for each date. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works. I spent too much time writing it, so I have to leave it at that. Let me know if you need explanations!

```
def func(df1):
    idx = df1.index.get_level_values(0)[0]
    df1 = df1.loc[idx]
    return (df1['Values'] / df1.loc['Calc']['Values']).to_frame()

df.groupby(level=0).apply(func)
```

Comment: It did work perfectly in some cases but I ended up isolating the value and adding an extra_column for my code so I avoid some data wrangling error. Thanks!